# Kth shortest path in a given MAZE c++

Tags: path, shortest

You are given a cost matrix of dimensions m X n.The problem is to find the minimal path from 
top-left corner to some cell in the matrix.The total cost of a path is sum total of cost of all cells visited in the path.Only 2 moves are allowed: either to go down by a row, or move right by a column. You cannot leave the matrix at any time Also, some of the cells are marked as obstacles and cannot be stepped upon.
Several queries of the form: tx ty k are to be answered. The output for this query should be kth 
minimum cost of a path from top-left corner to cell indexed at ty column in tx row
CONSTRAINTS:

```
1<= m,n <= 100 0 <= tx < m 0 <= ty <n 1 <= k <= 101 
The obstacles in matrix are marked by "##" (quotes only for clarity) 
The values in every cell that is not an obstacle, varies from -9 to 99 only. 
tx and ty are both 0-indexed. 
If k exceeds the total paths to cell (tx, ty) output "Not so many paths" 
If (tx, ty) is an obstacle, output "Obstacle". 
There will never be an obstacle on the top-left corner or bottom-right corner.


Input: 
 The first line contains the number of test cases T, 
 The first line of each test case contains two space-separated integers m and n. 
 The next m lines each contain n integers, denoting the matrix. 
 The next line contains an integer q, denoting the number of queries to come. 
 The next q lines each contain 3 space separated integers, tx ty and k 
Output: 
 For each query output the kth shortest path
```

What i tried is backtracking which resulted in TLE.(time limit was given 1 sec).Whenever i reach the destination cell i stored that path cost in vector..and in the end after sorting the vector printed the Kth value in vector...But i need more efficient way to solve the problem ..can dynamic programming be used here..???

Comment: Why not just apply [Djikstra's/A*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra's_algorithm)? It will work much better than a DFS ("backtracking") for finding the shortest path here.

Comment: Does Djikstra Helps with Obstacles ..and does it help with returning the Kth minimal path..??

Comment: Obstacles are simply nodes with no links (or links with an infinitely high cost) to them and thus cannot be explored. To find the Kth minimum path, keep running Djikstra's until it is found - ignore the first K_{-1}'th better cases / terminal conditions.

Comment: Wud u please explain more how will i leave those first K-1 th better cases ...I am not getting u ..each time we will run Djikstra we get the same result right..?? Then what will be issue of leaving the those better cases..:/

Comment: Run it once, but run a *modified* version that won't terminate until the K'th best path is found. Normally it just stops when the solution node is found; but use a counter to not let it stop until the solution node is found K times.

Comment: Nd y u sure that Djisktra(BFS) will work better..??

Comment: Yes. I am very sure. The DFS is very inefficient for this problem due to the high branching factor.

Comment: And in each run Djisktra gives the next best possible path. correct me if i am wrong..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a dynamic programming solution for this.

Use a 3D matrix `cost[M][N][K]` where `cost[x][y][i]` will represent the ith shortest path to reach cell (x, y) from the top right hand corner.

Notice that each cell (x, y) can only be reached from cell (x-1, y) and (x, y-1). Therefore, we can process the cells in sequential order using for loops. This will ensure cell (x-1, y) and (x, y-1) will be processed before cell (x, y) for any cell (x, y).

```
for (int x = 0; x < m; x++) {
    for (int y = 0; y < n; y++) {
       //Process
    }
}
```

Assuming we have already computed all the k shortest path for cell (x-1, y) and (x, y-1), you can compute the k shortest path for cell (x, y) by sorting the 2*k shortest paths leading to cell (x-1, y) and (x, y-1) by picking the smallest cost ones and adding the cost of reaching cell (x, y) to the picked paths.
This can be done using a conventional sorting algorithm yielding O(k log k) time per cell. However, since the k shortest paths for cell (x-1, y) and (x, y-1) are already sorted, one can actually sort them in O(k) running time by using a technique similar to mergesort if the time limit is really tight. This yields a best possible run time of O(nmk) and memory O(nmk).

Memory can be reduced by only saving the last row since only the x-1 row is required when computing the xth row, hence we can discard all the rows before the x-1 row.